# How to achieve Data-Driven Testing through JSON and EXCEL both in Protractor through a node package?

Tags: protractor

My Code:

```
 browser.get('http://10.32.128.249:9090/');
 browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
 var a = element(by.id("username"));
 var b = element(by.id("password"));
```

After Login there is a Sign In Button.

I need to input some data into username and password through excel and JSON simultaneously.

Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use excel-as-json package which helps to convert excel to Json.
So our code will be written to handle only JSON files. 
Here is the Link [excel to json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/excel-as-json)

```
var convertExcel = require('excel-as-json').processFile;
convertExcel('path to store xlsx', 'path of json');

describe ('nsWeb Login Page Data Driven' , function() {
  browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;


beforeEach(function(){
  browser.get('http://10.32.128.249:9090/');
  browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
 });

it('To verify Login, using Data Driven Technique from Json file', function()        
 {
  var testData = require('D:/json path');
  for(var i=0;i<=4;i++)  // if there are 5 data in json
 { 
  var a = element(by.id("username"));
  var b = element(by.id("password"));
  a.sendKeys(testData[i].username);
  b.sendKeys(testData[i].passwordField); 
 }
}); 
it('To verify Login, using Data Driven Technique from Excel file',     
 function(){
  var testData1 = require('D:/json path');
  var a = element(by.id("username"));
  var b = element(by.id("password"));
  a.sendKeys(testData1[0].username);
  b.sendKeys(testData1[0].passwordField); 
  });
 });
```

Example of JSON:

```
[
  {
    "username": "kishan",
    "password": "patel"
  },
  {
    "username": "kishan",
    "password": "patel"
  },
  {
    "username": "kishan",
    "password": "patel"
  },
  {
    "username": "kishan",
    "password": "patel"
  },
  {
    "username": "kishan",
    "password": "patel"
  }
]
```

Same values you can put in excel and it will be converted to JSON.

Hope it helps.